# Porting OpenCV to NIOS2 processor

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to cross compile OpenCV library for ALTERA Nios 2 processor but I have little experience in makefiles and I want to know what are the steps generally followed to create a makefiles , makefile for opencv , removing the gui components and finally building the library with my application .

Comment: Too specific. Ask it on OpenCV mailing list.